# c# dynamic as delegate parameter

Tags: c#, dynamic, delegates

Heyo,
i'm currently working on a school assignment and we should use delegate's.
So I got a delegate:

```
public delegate AVLNode Insert(AVLNode node, dynamic key);
```

And I got two different Insert Methods, the one takes a node and a string and the other one should take a node and a float as a paramter.
The problem I face now is that the delegate doesn't accept these method's because they don't match.

How can I fix tis issue without declaring the string and the int parameter as a dynamic? Sorry if my problem isn't described well, first time describing any coding problem.

Like I already said, I want a delegate with a dynamic as the parameter while both methods which will be used with the delegate have either a string or a int as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, why do you want a dynamic parameter for your key over an object which is also accepting of every type? You can then use pattern matching to ensure they are either a float or a string since you can't overload delegates. Making something dynamic also involves a lot of type checking during runtime. Why a delegate for an insert method? Do you want users to write their own insert method into a collection I assume is managed by a class? That makes no guarantee the insert delegate will insert successfully.

Generally, you mostly see delegates being used as guaranteed signatures that fulfill an operation that the user defines. For example: `TimerCallback` being a delegate for what happens every time a timer ticks, `SpanAction<T, TArg>` for letting users work with a given span and state object, custom events letting users create their own operations when something occurs, etc.

Anyways, wherever you're using your delegate, you want to make sure it is either a string or a float/int (you used both float and int seemingly interchangeably in your description). You can use this example to check for both types:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var dyn = func(); // Returns dynamic, unknown type
    if (dyn is string s)
        Console.WriteLine($"string: {s}");
    else if (dyn is int i)
        Console.WriteLine($"int: {i}");
    else if (dyn is float f) Console.WriteLine($"float: {f}");
}
```

Or you can use regular if statements:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var dyn = func(); // Returns dynamic, unknown type
    switch (dyn)
    {
        case string s:
            Console.WriteLine($"string: {s}");
            break;
        case int i:
            Console.WriteLine($"int: {i}");
            break;
        case float f:
            Console.WriteLine($"float: {f}");
            break;
    }
}
```

But seriously, I cannot stress this enough: everything you want can very likely just be done with the object type!!! While both object and dynamic types allow for any object, dynamic allows for even specified derived types to be reassigned to any other type! For example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var dyn = GetDynamicInt(); // dynamic int
    var n = GetInt(); // not dynamic int

    dyn = Random.Shared.NextDouble(); // Now it's not an int but do you know that? Will you know that?
    n = Random.Shared.NextDouble(); // Guaranteed type, this throws
}
```

Comment: First of all. Thanks, it really helped me.
And secondly, why I want a delegate for an insert funtction, because I "need" to do that. It's an assignment that didn't got a rework for a couple of years and the teacher doesn't have time to rework it. That's why I must use it in that way.
But still thanks, it really helped me.